# how to access the stringArray outside a Thread in array adapter

Tags: android

**how to access the stringArray outside a Thread in array adapter. in the following code the stringArray is declared inside the thread which is to be accepted in the array adapter  below.

when we try & run the code it throws an null exception providing an null array in the array adapter.
               (plz focus on the **...** marked code)

```
source = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1)
 dest = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView2);

    readStopName();

                   **adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,stringArray);**
    //how to access the stringArray outside a Thread in array adapter 

                   source.setAdapter(adapter);
                      dest.setAdapter(adapter);
                   source.setThreshold(2);
                   dest.setThreshold(2);
                addListenerOnButton();
            }

            public void readStopName() 
            {
                new Thread() 
                {
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        // TODO Run network requests here.


                        /* try */
                        try 
                        {
                            readFeed = builder.toString();
                            json = new JSONObject(readFeed);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(
                                    json.optString("ResultSet"));
                            System.out.println("OKAY_4!!");

                         stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                            //JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                            for(int i = 1, count = jsonArray.length(); i< count; i++)
                            {
                                try 
                                {
                                     json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                     System.out.println("OKAY!!" +json.toString());
                                    **stringArray.add(json.toString());**
                                   //how to access the stringArray outside a Thread in array adapter 

                                }

                                catch (JSONException e) 
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            } 

                        }
                         catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }.start();
                System.out.println("OKAY!!" + builder.toString());


            }
```

Comment: You're using the null array to instantiate your adapter and then you're giving it to a Thread that instantiate it. I don't see how it is supposed to work...the Thread execution starts later and Android is trying to use your null array before it. Plese note also that ArrayList is not thread safe.

Comment: use asynctask you can return your string arary in doInbackground and in onPostExecute use the param in adapter

Comment: Yes asynctask is definitely the way to go here.